# Mongoose updateOne() going through okay but not updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this request:

```
// PUT that updates a user. 
router.put('/api/user/:id', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { email, name, avatar } = req.body

    const userId = req.body._id
    const conditions = {
        _id : userId
    }

    const user = {$set: { "email": email, "name": name, "avatar": avatar } }
    
    User.updateOne(conditions, user).then(doc => {
        if (!doc) { return res.status(404).end() }
        return res.status(200).json(doc)
    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
})
```

And I get this response from the request:

```
{
    "n": 0,
    "nModified": 0,
    "ok": 1
}
```

If you can find it on StackOverflow about the `updateOne()` method in mongoose I've probably tried it. The document isn't updating no matter what I try.

Edit: I've tried using an ObjectID in the query instead and the same result.

Edit 2: I figured it out. Was using req.body.id instead of req.params.id and I was using parameters to send the request. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Are you sure your condition get any result?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be for some reason.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I advise you to read the how to ask a good question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: you are passing wrong variable for user id `req.body._id` it should be `req.params.id`

Comment: You are missing await, UpdateOne behaves like a promise, without await this won't resolve.

Answer (score 1):

`nModified == 0` implies that you have no user matching this id,

your route is `put /api/user/:id` but **your user id is in req.params.id and not in req.body._id**

Answer (score 0):

A couple tips:

Try running the same query from mongodb at the command line, see if you get any results.
Is the "campaign_id" defined as an ObjectId in your schema? If so, try searching using the ObjectId type.

Try to change the query to :

```
const ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId; 
  const conditions = {
        _id : new ObjectId(userId)
    }
```

The reason for not updating is - mongoose is unable to search the with the id you provided.

Comment: Doing this and adding the upsert: true object in the request made it work, meaning the document possibly didn't exist in the first place anyway? I thought I'd tried this as well. In any case, thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually nvm, it only upserted a field called index and the _id for some reason, back to square one. EDIT: when I run a get on the same user it returns the user so I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update a document based on `_id` you can use `findByIdAndUpdate()`

```
const userId = req.body._id;
const user =  { "email": email, "name": name, "avatar": avatar } 
User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId , user, 
    function (err, docs) { 
    if (err){ 
        console.log(err) 
    } 
    else{ 
        console.log("Updated User : ", docs); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: For some reason this lists the user as null, even though if I run a get request on the exact same id I get a result.

Answer (score 0):

In case you've set your DB to strict mode don't forget to add `strict:false` in options when adding new keys. Otherwise, inserts will be silently ignored. I've just spent 2 hours wondering why my inserts don't get saved in DB despite not throwing any error.

See dos
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict

```
const conditions = {
    _id
}

const dateToUpdate =  {
    $set: {
        "email": "email",
        "name": "name",
        "avatar": "avatar"
    }
}

const updateRecord = await models.pdDealModel.updateOne(conditions,dateToUpdate,{
        upsert:false,
        strict:false
    }
    
)
```